# Grant JavaApplet permission to socket

Tags: java, security, sockets, applet

I have a Java Applet, which needs to talk to another windows app through socket. And I am keeping getting `AccessControlException`. I know I can modify the `java.policy` file under `java/lib` to grant the access on a specific port.

The problem is the app sometime pick random port, I can't just define every port in the applet policy file. Is there a way to grant all port access to my Java Applet?

Are they anything else I should do besides modifying the java.policy file?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "127.0.0.1:3399" "connect,resolve")
```

Comment: did you try reading the javadoc for SocketPermission? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/SocketPermission.html

Comment: Why does the server pick a random port?